# Is it possible to pull text from another website and place it in another site using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if it is possible to have people post text to something like a wordpress blog and then have javascript on another page pull that string data (from wordpress) into another site and place it in a div or paragraph tag. I'm very new to javascript and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, the Same Origin Policy prevents this.

Comment: @Diodeus, There's always CORS, if the origin allows...

Comment: @Joshua, Can you do anything server-side?  If so, proxying content is very easy.

Comment: @Diodeus, I mention it because it is possible he is in control of both sites.  Browser adoption for CORS isn't bad these days, if it's only secondary content that needs to be loaded client-side for some reason.

Comment: The problem is that I need to have a few sections of a site be updateable without using a CMS or giving anyone who will be updating the information full access to wreak havoc on everything. Thats why I wanted them to put the body text somewhere else, like in a wordpress blog and then have javascript pull the text from the blog into the section that should update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the data from a wordpress blog using their [XML-RPC Blogger API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Blogger_API)

there is also [a way to get the data in JSON format](http://digwp.com/2010/05/wordpress-json-api-plugin/)

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for, it'll take some time for me to figure out but this is it, thanks!